# Auto-refreshing using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function which updates a time_remaining span on the page.

```
function update() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check_time.php',
    data: 'checktime=true',
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(data) {
        $(".time_remaining").html(data);
        window.setTimeout(update, 2000);
        var time=(html(data));
        alert(time);
        if(time<=0)
        {
            $(".time_remaining").html("now");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".time_remaining").html(data);
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $("#notice_div").html('Timeout contacting server..');
      window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
    }
});
};
```

My only problem is this line:

```
var time=(html(data));
```

It simply does not define the variable correctly. Any pointers?

Comment: What does 'data' look like? Is it valid HTML? Some browsers will not allow some HTML to be processed as XML in this way, e.g. <TR> tags without a <TABLE>

Comment: What did you expect that particular line to do?  Is there a function named html?

Comment: What do you think that is supposed to do? I have never seen that syntax before. data should have your return value in it. What type of value are you returning? It looks like maybe parseInt(data) might be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you use only

```
var time = data;
```

Answer (score 1):

(html(data)) is not a defined method used in this fasion.

```
var time = $(".time_remaining").html();
```

or

```
var time = data;
```

Comment: ...or $(".time_remaining").html(data);